# Computing Itô differential of conditional expectation process (Heston SDE)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, itos-lemma, sde

Going through [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/43771692_A_Decomposition_Formula_for_Option_Prices_in_the_Heston_Model_and_Applications_to_Option_Pricing_Approximation)
on Heston's model, where the variance evolves following the SDE
\begin{equation}
\label{sd1}
d\sigma^2_t = \kappa \bigg( m - \color{red}{\sigma^2_t} \bigg)dt + \nu \sqrt {\sigma^2_t} dW_t  
\end{equation}
with $\kappa, m, \nu$ being constants, and $W_t$ a Brownian Motion (corrected errata shown in red).

the author defines
\begin{equation}
\label{sd}
M_t := \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[\sigma^2_s \vert \mathcal{F}_t ] ds
\end{equation}

and then proceeds to claim (without further details) that
\begin{equation}
\label{sd2}
dM_t = \nu \sqrt {\sigma^2_t} \bigg( \int_t^T \exp[-\kappa(s-t)]  ds \bigg)dW_t
\end{equation}

How can one use Itô's lemma to compute the differential? I thought about first defining $X_t := \mathbb{E}[\sigma^2_s \vert \mathcal{F}_t ]$ and computing $dX_t$, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the SDE for the Heston model - it violates the affine property in the drift term. In other words, the paper has a typo. The correct SDE is:

$$
d v_t = \kappa (m-v_t) dt + \nu \sqrt{v_t} dw_t
$$
where $v_t := \sigma_t^2$ is the variance.

Let $\xi_t^T := \mathbb{E}_t [ v_T]$ denote the forward variance and see that

$$
\begin{align}
\xi_{t}^{T} & = \mathbb{E}_t [ v_T] \\
& = \mathbb{E}_t \left[ v_t + \int_{t}^{T} \kappa (m-v_u) du + \int_{t}^{T} \nu \sqrt{v_u} dw_u \right] \\
& = v_t + \int_{t}^{T} \kappa (m- \xi_t^u ) d u
\end{align}
$$
In differential form (with respect to $T$)
$$
d \xi_t^T = k (m-\xi_t^T) dT
$$
Using the integrating factor method yields $\xi$ to be
$$
\xi_t^T = m + e^{-\kappa (T-t)} ( \xi_t^t - m)
$$
In differential format (with respect to $t$)
$$
d \xi_t^T = e^{-\kappa (T-t)} \nu \sqrt{\xi_t^t} dw_t
$$
Therefore the differential for $M$ (with respect to $t$) is
$$
d M_t = \int_{0}^{T} d \xi_t^s ds = \nu \sqrt{v_t} \left[ \int_{0}^{T} e^{-\kappa (s-t)} ds \right]  d w_t
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The steps are really clear. Would you mind adding a few more detail in the solving of the differential equation using the integrating factor? Also the final result is missing the square root of v_t, as it comes from the previous equation where xi_t^t = v_t , right?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was missing the square root in the final expression for v_t, I have corrected my typo now. I will leave the integrating factor derivation as an exercise for you to solve - it is not that difficult. If you get stuck, take a look at some "integrating factor examples" around on the exchange or on the web - there are plenty.